# Exadata - Query with join between 2 databases

Tags: exadata

In Exadata, I have two different databases.

Is it possible to perform a join between a table that is in database A, to a table that is in database B?

On the standard Oracle database engine, I know this is not possible except via a db-link but I have a doubt with Exadata... If anyone can give me any information !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB Link *is* the way. Exadata is essentially a storage technology; so the fact that it's Exadata is irrelavant for this is question